# Jvectormap Custom Names

Tags: javascript, jquery, pointers, jvectormap

I want to make custom names for the regions in my maps, I'm using the map of the Netherlands and it shows the names of the provinces when I hover.

Instead I want to add the cities that are in it.

So I need to change the names it shows; But when I do that it gives me a syntax error.

Im using these scripts:

```
<script src="assets/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://jvectormap.com/js/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
```

I cant find my way in the .min file and cant find the non-minimalised version anywhere on the internet.

Next to that I cant find anything regarding this topic on the internet itself.

Greetings, Chris.

Answer (score 0):

There is a onRegionLabelShow method that you can override.  You just need to change the html in the label.

```
    onRegionLabelShow: function (event, label, code) {
        label.html('City 1<br/>City 2<br/>');
    },
```